# Office JS based Outlook Add-in to capture appointment click event

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am currently working on Office JS based Outlook Addin where my main purpose is to capture Appoinment Item click event and from that click I will open up the Taskpane.

I have also checked this link provided by microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest in which they have provided very few event based activation events.

But I am still wondering if there is a way to achieve it.

I tried several things like Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync inside the launchevent.js file and this is the error message I am getting:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addHandlerAsync')

Your help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It appears your scenario is about selecting an appointment / event on the calendar surface and then opening up a taskpane to view/interact with the selected appointment / event. If that is accurate, this behavior is not supported by the product. Outlook add-in feature requests are tracked on our Tech Community page (https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit a request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests are considered when we go through our planning process.